# Does ranking of journals matter in Bioinformatics?

Tags: journals, ranking, bioinformatics

Does the rankings Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, and Q5 by Scimago Journal & Country Rank matter when looking for post-doc? I am interested to know about Bioinformatics and Computational Biology.

Comment: I think this is more regional than disciplinary.

Comment: What @AnonymousPhysicist said.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking about. Does "looking for a post-doc" mean you're trying to hire a postdoctoral scholar, or that you want to be hired as a postdoc? In addition, what does "matter" mean? Many people will favor publications in fancy, well-known journals during the hiring process, but it's not a great system. Are you asking whether you should try to publish in higher-ranked journals?